# Widgets for Desktop in Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-environments, widgets

[LibreOffice Impress - Adding Slide Themes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcnJ2Hu9NOY)

For the fisrt few seconds of this video we see the presenter's desktop, displaying what resembles, to me, as widgets like in Windows (7 namely). What is this, and how do I get it?

Comment: Looks like [Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net) to me.

Answer (score 1):

What is being used in the video is a program called Conky. It displays system information on the desktop. It is available in the Ubuntu Software Center, search for "conky".

The default theme isn't nearly as pretty as the one that guys is using in the video. You have to edit a config file to change the appearance of the Conky widget. There are many configurations out there that you can copy paste into the config file and try out.

Some general help with using Conky can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpConky